# How should we handle id on Hibernate 6 on Sql server

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate

We are migrating from Hibernate 5 to 6, and are having issues with the conversion of our id.

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class Entity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID") 
    @Convert(converter = UUIDConverter.class)
    private UUID id = UUID.randomUUID();
}
```

The converter is set up like this:

```
@Converter 
public class UUIDConverter implements AttributeConverter<UUID, String> {
    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(UUID attribute) {
        return attribute.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public UUID convertToEntityAttribute(String dbData) {
        return UUID.fromString(dbData);
    }
}
```

We are using Sql Server, and the id is a uniqueidentifier in the database. If we save an object with id `8f935c03-0971-445e-9526-0ecbc743b470`, this will be saved in the database as `035C938F-7109-5E44-9526-0ECBC743B470`.

Any suggestion on how to solve this? What is a best-practice way to handle id`s? Some documentation say that we should not combine @Id with @Convert, but we have not found out what the alternative is.

We have tried converting to uppercase in the converter and we have tried using in IdClass.

Comment: Why do you even need to convert the UUID? Also, have a look at [this](https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-and-uuid-identifiers/) and [this](https://thorben-janssen.com/generate-uuids-primary-keys-hibernate/) regarding the usage of UUID

Answer (score 1):

JPA now comes with support for `UUID` built-in, so it should be as simple as:

```java
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class Entity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private UUID id;
}
```

Or, if you want some more control, check out the `@UuidGenerator` annotation in `org.hibernate.annotations`.

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/UuidGenerator.html